# Animation not working when saving to database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a rotate animation on a toggle button as below, if I ran independently it works just fine.

```
val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, itemView.toggleButton.pivotX, itemView.toggleButton.pivotY)
rotateAnimation.duration = AppConstants.ROTATE_ANIMATION_TIME
rotateAnimation.fillAfter = true
rotateAnimation.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
itemView.toggleButton.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
```

But when I am executing a room query after the animation, the animation is not working!

```
mTaskDAO.update(task)
```

Comment: I may be wrong but is your query being executed on the UI thread and so your animation get screwed because of time passing? try moving it to another thread and see if it works

Comment: I moved it to another thread using Rx, even executed the query first and then the animation, but no success!

Answer (score 0):

I was manking the DAO query return a `Flowable`. In room if you return a `Flowable` then whenever data changes, all the queries returning `Flowable` will get initiated automatically. So basically whenever animation was initiated, room would update the data and recycler view would refresh the adapter.